# FILAB "Connect to VM display" missing credentials

Tags: vnc, fiware, filab

I have a FILAB (FIWARE Cloud) instance I am trying to connect to through VM Display Tool (VNC display) found when looking at the details of the instance, under Connection tab. I have successfully established a SSH connection for other instance to which I have floating IP assigned. For both instances VNC connection gives me login prompt, but I don't know what are the credentials for login.

I have tried my FIWARE credentials and also based on [this thread](https://forge.fiware.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2988&group_id=7&atid=162) and one other:

- root/-
- localadmin/welcome
- ubuntu/-

I have also tried the option "Change password" for this instance but I am experiencing same issue as [HERE](https://jira.fi-ware.org:8443/browse/HELP-1069), ie. error 501: "notImplemented".

Nowhere in presentations and documentation about setting the FILAB infrastructure have I found what credentials are for VNC, or how to set them.

Has anyone solved this issues and connected through VNC to FILAB instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had the same issue here. "root" and "fiware" passwords are not yet disclosed so we proceeded as follows:

1. We assigned temporarily the external IP to the new VM
2. Login via SSH
3. Create a new user and grant privileges (useradd, passwd, visudo)
4. Now test the VM display with that user
5. Reassign the external IP to the original VM

Now you can access your new VM from any browser :)

Some advices:

-If the VM display is not answering to your keystrokes (i.e. on firefox), you can inspect the sourcecode of the HTML webview and use the direct link to the noVNC server in a new window (something like http://a.b.c.d:6080/vnc_auto.html?token=XXXX)

-noVNC is handy for connecting anywhere, but if you are working a lot on the new VM I would recommend to connect via SSH to the VM with the external IP and then from that connection open a new ssh connection within the local shared network (you just need to get the .pem file)